# Powershell Downloading and Executing Files (File or Directory is corrupted and unreadable)

Tags: powershell, download, execute

I've been trying to download and execute files with powershell. Everything works fine, Powershell downloads the File from "Workupload.com" and puts it in my /user folder.
This works perfectly with pictures, and I can open them as well after they are downloaded.

However it doesnt work when I try it with .exe or .txt files..
Here is my Code:

```
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = 'link to my .exe on workupload'
$dst = 'FireFox-Installer.exe' #Not adding a Path just puts the File in the User Folder
$WebClient.DownloadFile($url, $dst)
Start-Process $dst 'FireFox-Installer.exe'
```

Now when I try to open the file I get an Error that the File is corrupted and unreadable. I wonder how I fix that.. Is the Windows-Defender blocking it? Is my Code wrong? Or is it the File-Hoster which causes the errors?

Here is my error-code:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process $dst 'FireFox-Installer.exe'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Would really appreciate some help since im kind of new to Powershell, thank you everyone! :)

Comment: What are those // that you use to write comments for the variable $dst? You have to use # to write comments in Powershell.
Also, Start-Process won't work like that because it would take $dst for the first argument and 'FireFox-Installer.exe' for a second one. If you want to join paths, use join-path
`Start-Process (Join-Path $dst 'FireFox-Installer.exe')`

Comment: Opps, well thats not part of my Code anyways, I just wrote that so People understand the File Destination. Thanks tho

Comment: No worries. I edited my first comment. Try using join-path to create a proper filename to give as an argument to Start-Process.

Comment: I used this Code now "Start-Process (Join-Path $dst 'FireFox-Installer.exe')" but now I just get a different Error which is "Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: The path is probably wrong then. Put the Start-Process line in comment and below it write:
`Write-Host (Join-Path $dst 'FireFox-Installer.exe')`
And check if the path is correct. If not, you probably did something wrong while building the path in $dst

Comment: Yeah you were right, I had to make some changes regarding the path. But Still the File is corrupted and unreadable.. Im kinda confused whats causing it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I just tried this and it worked as expected:

```
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = 'https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/79.0/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Installer.exe'
$dst = 'C:\Temp'
$WebClient.DownloadFile($url, (Join-Path $dst 'FireFox-Installer.exe'))
Start-Process (Join-Path $dst 'FireFox-Installer.exe')
```

I just added another `Join-Path` for the destination argument of `DownloadFile`
If it still doesn't work, I would suggest you to check your link and to test your Firefox-Installer.exe file.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your destination root folder (e.g. \\myserver\myshare) to Trusted Sites in IE, then close and restart your PS session, does the original $dst work?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).